# How to count records as "0" that have value "0" when using WHERE x = 1

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

I have a table structure that looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/DswITVz]

I have a perfectly working query that counts how many records there have been per day the last 30 days. It looks likes this:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, COUNT(id) AS emails FROM 'emails WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

This outputs the following which is perfectly fine:

[image: http://imgur.com/QkwTgiD]

However, the next thing seems too difficult for me to imagine. Now I want to count how many records there have been per day the last 30 days BUT only where newsletter = 1.

I've tried to put a WHERE statement looking like this:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, COUNT(*) AS emails, nyhedsbrev FROM emails WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month AND nyhedsbrev = 1 GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

... And that outputs the following:

[image: http://imgur.com/kIVKYjc]

The problem is, that its omitting the records with newsletter = 0 and there by I cant compare my first query against the new one, as the dates doesnt match. I know that is because I use WHERE newsletter = 1.

In stead of omitting the record I want a query that just puts a "0" from that date. How can I do this? The final query should be outputting this:

[image: http://imgur.com/XlcovbN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply use `SUM()` and `IF()` to get the desired output:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(timestamp) AS date, 
    COUNT(*) AS emails,
    SUM(IF(nyhedsbrev > 0, 1, 0)) as nyhedsbrev_count
FROM 
    emails 
WHERE 
    timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month
GROUP BY 
    DATE(timestamp)
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4706f/1/0)

**Edit**: You might even be able to simplify it, since it's a boolean, and simply use `SUM(nyhedsbrev)`, but this REQUIRES that `nyhedsbrev` is **only** `0` or `1`:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(timestamp) AS date, 
    COUNT(*) AS emails,
    SUM(nyhedsbrev) as nyhedsbrev_count
FROM 
    emails 
WHERE 
    timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month
GROUP BY 
    DATE(timestamp)
```

[image]

Comment: @NikolajSneftrupLundJensen You're welcome - make sure you check the edit, as you might simply be able to use `SUM(nyhedsbrev)`.

Comment: Yes exactly. I've ended up using only that and its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly best to get a list of the dates and then left join that against sub queries to get the counts you require.

Something like this

```
SELECT Sub1.date, Sub2.emails, IFNULL(Sub3.emails, 0)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(timestamp) AS date
FROM emails 
WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, COUNT(id) AS emails 
FROM emails WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)) Sub2
ON Sub2.date = Sub3.date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, COUNT(*) AS emails 
FROM emails 
WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month AND nyhedsbrev = 1 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)) Sub3
ON Sub1.date = Sub3.date
```

(you can probably optimise one subselect of this away, but I have done it in full to make it obvious how it is working)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming newsletter is boolean 1/0 values then this might give you the table that you want:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, COUNT(*) AS emails, nyhedsbrev 
FROM emails WHERE timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month GROUP BY DATE(timestamp),nyhedsbrev ;
```

Just adding another GROUP BY parameter.